# Drawing an equation in Quartz

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

I have got experience in iPhone programming but not really in graphics programming.

I decided to make a 2d game and choose Quartz 2D for this purpose (I'm familiar with Open GL, but quartz seems to be easier for a 2d game).

Is there a built-in way to draw a graph of a math formula in Quartz? For beginning it will be only a parabola (y=ax^2+bx+c) but the equation itself will become more complex in the future.

It may be pretty slow if I will draw the parabola using my own algorithm (from separate lines or dots).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could calculate some discrete samples of the equations you want to render.
Your graph will look smooth or polygonal depending on how many samples you provide.

[This blog post](http://www.supermegaultragroovy.com/blog/2009/10/06/drawing-waveforms/) describes how to render waveforms for a Mac OS X application.
As the author is using Quartz and you can probably adapt his approach for your problem.
The blog post uses the convenient CGPathAddLines() method to create a path from a point array.
If you'd like to construct your path piece by piece, you could use some of the following methods:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); 
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, ...);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, ...);
CGPathAddArc(path, ...);
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using something like the [CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) framework?

Answer (score 2):

For plotting an arbitrary math expression, you can use Graham Cox's [GCMathParser](http://www.apptree.net/parser.htm) to take in an NSString containing the expression and evaluate that expression for various values.  You can then use [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) (as suggested by Jasarien) to create a graph of these values.  In fact, I have a sample application that does just this, which I will be adding to the project soon.

Answer (score 1):

Quartz uses [Bezier curves](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000959-CH202-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in to Quartz for this; you'll have to plot each point individually using math.